# LibreOffice interface is not showing

Tags: libreoffice

I just recently installed LibreOffice on Ubuntu 11.04 through terminal the drop down options didn't show at all. please help me to fix this[Cant see the drop down options](http://img851.imageshack.us/i/screenshot1si.png/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the same thing happen with a more "traditional" font? It seems to me like it's the font that causes this

Comment: by the way, all three top sites from a google search for "free fonts" are excellent ones . If i were you i would look for a better made font that would look like the one i had - thus getting both the working menus and the font you like. I used to have rather strange fonts (eg : my own handwriting) for quite some time without any problem on libreoffice's menus